# Bitstamp API signature in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bitcoin

I'm trying to access balance of Bitstamp account with API.

```
secret = "secret"
key = "key"
nonce = (1000*Time.now.to_f).to_i.to_s
client_id = "123123"

message = nonce + client_id + key
signature = HMAC::SHA256.hexdigest(secret, message).upcase

puts open("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/balance/?nonce=#{nonce}&key=#{key}&signature=#{signature}").read
```

it clearly generates all required attributes

```
https://www.bitstamp.net/api/balance/?nonce=1392137355403&key=key&signature=955A3FFC6FEBE69385B9503307873DBCD21E9B7B8EDE67817FFF70961189CE50
```

yet the error says attributes are missing, why?

```
{"error": "Missing key, signature and nonce parameters"}
```

Comment: I had a quick look at the API and replicated your fault. I think either the service is not working as intended, or probably more likely the error message is just being unhelpful. The documentation suggests you use POST, but gives no indication of how you should send or format the request parameters. I would suggest the Bitstamp developers need more detailed documentation, better error messages, or perhaps reference clients.

Comment: That was it, I had to send the request as POST.

Comment: @Sergey - Have you solved the above problem? I am also stuck at same here? The API is not well documented. Can you send me your sign generation code and post request code if you have solved the problem.

Comment: @Jeff I added the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was sending the request as GET instead of POST. Here is the full code I am using now that works.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'
require 'hmac-sha2'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

def bitstamp_private_request(method, attrs = {})
  secret = "xxx"
  key = "xxx"
  client_id = "xxx"
  nonce = nonce_generator

  message = nonce + client_id + key
  signature = HMAC::SHA256.hexdigest(secret, message).upcase

  url = URI.parse("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/#{method}/")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  http.use_ssl = true

  data = {
    nonce: nonce,
    key: key,
    signature: signature
  }
  data.merge!(attrs)
  data = data.map { |k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&')

  headers = {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }

  resp = http.post(url.path, data, headers)
  console_log "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/#{method}/"
  resp.body
end

def nonce_generator
  (Time.now.to_f*1000).to_i.to_s
end
```